# How to read a line and split into string and float values in a C program?

Tags: c, string

I have a file that contains 80 characters per line. I want to go to a particular line that starts with "ATOM".

I tried with `fscanf(f1," %s%*[^\n]", rec)` and compare `rec` with `strcmp(rec,"ATOM")`, but it reads the next line from the match.
I also tried with `fscanf("line_format", variables)`, but this reads somewhere else from the file.

The line is

```
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      36.643 -24.862   8.890  1.00 24.11             N
```

From this I want to read character by character and assign it to variables. I have a problem with the `float` values and spaces. If I find a space in a place of particular variable how do I read it? How do I read the `float` values if there is no space between them?

Answer (score 1):

You can read each line from the input file using `fgets()`, tokenise it using `strtok()` or `strtok_r()`, compare the first token to "ATOM", and then parse the rest of the tokens using `atof()` or `atoi()` to convert them to floating point or integer numbers if necessary.

Although this is a bit of an overkill since the `ATOM` record in the PDB file has a well defined structure with fixed sized fields and any conformant pdb file would be much easier to parse. You just pick the relevant substrings and pass them to `atof()` or `atoi()`.

Comment: Can you give some more examples? This has given me some idea but still has not cleared logic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you had an error in your (not shown) `line_format`. You really should be able to just do:

```
if( fscanf(f1, "ATOM %d %s %s %s %d %f %f %f %f %f %s", /* ... */) == 11 )
{
  /* store/analyze/print the parsed values */
}
```

Note of course that this runs the risk of overwriting the string arguments. You could use a more specific format string to limit the lengths.

Comment: ==11-can you tell me what it means?

Comment: fscanf returns the number of successful assignments.. in your case 11 numbers as specified in the  pdbformat.... after working 5 years with md simulations, I can only recommend not using that format... it is utterly crap. use the new [xml](http://pdbml.pdb.org/index.html) format.